# Windows Form Launching Another Form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am quite new to Visual Studio (Express) and C#.  I have made a windows form that accepts some user input then displays that input in a Message Box (that automatically comes with an "OK" button that closes the Message Box when clicked).

Instead I would like the user input collected by the first form to be displayed in a new form that displays a message (label), shows the input, and offers a choice of two buttons: one to accept and one to go back and change the input.

I have NO idea how to do this and any advice is appreciated.

Comment: It would be beneficial to show your code that shows how you are displaying the form for user entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need a confirm Message or something similar.
The MessageBox class offers this functionality.

```
   DialogResult btn = MessageBox.Show("your message", 
                                      "your title", 
                                      MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, 
                                      MessageBoxIcons.Question);
   if(btn == DialogResult.Cancel)
        // User canceled, return to the string editor 
   else
        // User confirmed, do you work
```

If you prefer there is also an enum for MessageBoxButtons.YesNo with corresponding DialogResult.Yes and DialogResult.No

[See here for a reference on MessageBoxButtons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons.aspx)
[See here for a reference on MessageBoxIcons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxicon.aspx)

Comment: How do I close the message box if the user selects "cancel"?

Comment: It closes by itself and returns DialogResult.Cancel

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to somehow pass the information from the first form to the second.  This can be done by setting properties on the child form, either through individual properties (strings, ints, etc.) or by a complete data structure (object).  The input form collects the information, creates the sub child form, sets properties on it, then displays the form.  Many other ways to do this, but start with the simple and then build up to the complex.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to [pass some data](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14122/Passing-Data-Between-Forms) to your second form, create property/properties on that form, or provide data via constructor parameters. Also assign [DialogResult property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult.aspx) for two buttons on second form. Set `DialogResult.OK` to button which will accept input. Verify value returned by second form, when you [show it as dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.window.showdialog.aspx) and do appropriate actions:

```
using(SecondForm secondForm = new SecondForm()
{
   secondForm.Data = yourData;
   if (secondForm.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
   {
       // go back and change input
       return
   }

   // accept input
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So your `Form2` needs to have some value, provided by whatever creates it, for it to exist.  There should never be an instance of Form2 without that information.  That tells you that it should be in that form's constructor (as opposed to a property on that form).

This means that in `Form1` you will have something like this:

```
string someData; //populate based off of user input
Form2 childForm = new Form2(someData);
//then hide current form and show child form
```

In Form2 you probably already have a constructor, you just need to modify it to something like:

```
public Form2(string someData) //TODO give better parameter name
{
  someLabel.Text = someData;
}
```

Next we need to deal with the child form going back to the parent form.  I feel the preferable way to deal with this is using events.  The form has a `FormClosing` event that you can attach to; this will allow your parent form to run some code when the child form is closed.

string someData; //populate based off of user input
Form2 childForm = new Form2(someData);

```
childForm.FormClosing += (sendingForm, args) =>
{
  this.Show();
  bool result = childForm.DidUserAccept;
}
```

Here I used a property on the child form `DidUserAccept`, for whether the user accepted or declined the value.  We'll need to define that in Form2:

```
public bool DidUserAccept {get; private set;}
```

In the button click handlers for accept/cancel you can set the result accordingly and then close the form (closing will trigger the closed event and runt he relevant code in `Form1`.